# In Sharepoint, how do you setup a column for 'person or group' with a default value?

Tags: sharepoint

Using the issue tracker in sharepoint 2007, I want to know how to set a default user to the my assigned to column.  Other column types include a 'default value' option, but for some reason the 'person or group' doesn't.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my specific situation, I ended up just using the 'created by' column and ditching the 'assigned to' column.  This gets set by default as the person who created the issue, so effectively becomes my default value.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported out of the box, so you'll have to use a Custom Field Type. For an example see

http://www.fftf.org/news/Oct06feed/Current_user_as_default_value_for_a_SharePoint_Person_or_Group_field.rss.html

Depending on how comfortable you are with SharePoint customization you can call this procedure either "very easy" (like they do) or completely overwhelming. If you run into any trouble, you know where to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Javascript rather than modifying the list itself for a low-impact solution. 
[Here](http://blogs.vbcity.com/skullcrusher/archive/2008/04/10/9024.aspx) is a blog post that describes exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [SharePoint Default Value](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint_default_value) Add-On, which inject a "default value" section into "Create Column" dialog.
[image]